# Making the name of shape node to be the same as the parent

Tags: python, maya

How can I make the name of the shape node to have similar name as its parent node? (Assuming there is only 1 shape node per geometry/object)

For eg. parent_geo is called `test_geo1`, however its shape node is `testing_geo2Shape` instead of `test_geo1Shape`

I tried doing the following:

```
all = cmds.ls(sl=True, dag=True, shapes=True)
for shape in all:
    prt = cmds.listRelatives(shape, parent=True)
    for i in prt:
        child = cmds.listRelatives(i, c = True)
        for c in child:
            cmds.rename(c, str(prt) + "Shape")
```

and I get some funky names such as `u_test_geo1__Shape` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all = cmds.ls(sl=True, dag=True, shapes=True)
for shape in all:
    ''' 
       shape contain the dag path
       exm.:
       grp_a
           grp_aShape
           grp_b
               grp_bShape
       print cmds.ls('grp_a', dag=1, shapes=1)
       >>('grp_a|grp_aShape', 'grp_b|grp_bShape')
       now rename the object, we have already the dag path so 
       the input of the rename command is unique, you can also split the dag 
       path by '|'[0] as parent
    '''
    cmds.rename(shape, "{0}Shape".format(cmds.listRelatives(shape, parent=True)[0]))
```

tested hierarchy was like:

```
grp_a
     shape grp_a
     grp_b
          same name like shape grp_c
grp_c
     shape grp_c
     grp_d
          same name like shape grp_c
grp_e
     same name like shape grp_c
```

select only the top grp

Comment: To find a mesh shape with ls, you may have to use the flag ni=True to prevent multiple intermediate shape to be detected. Before renaming, you may have to check if the name already exists in order to prevent maya to "rename your new name"

Comment: @ari gold, so I try testing with the zip and format method, I try out with a couple of selections - selecting everything/just the dag nodes/just the shape nodes etc, however I am not able to get the code working unfortunately.. Same goes for the latter code too

Comment: @dissidia true, for nested groups or more than one shape with the same name, i change that

Comment: @arigold Thank you. Actually I have managed to find an alternative way using the previous code that you have put up with some tweaking. Thanks again!